# Access contents of a node of custom content type

Tags: drupal, variables, drupal-7

I have a jquery slide show in the front page of this site I'm working on. I want to populate the slideshow with the contents of a node which is of a content type that i defined. The content type has multiple (image field and description). How do I access these contents from the front page.

Thanks in advance.

-- Aayush Shrestha

Comment: Well... Given that I know the id of the node. I just want to use the content type as a source for the pictures so that the client admin will also be able to edit the slideshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do the above mentioned task. Not sure if it is the most efficient way to do it but this is what I did.

Basically I loaded the content node using

```
$node = node_load($node_id);
```

Then I print_r()'ed the $node to see its array structure.
After that it was just a matter of accessing the value of the required field and echoing it at the required place. It looked something like this.

```
$slideArray = $node->field_slide['und'];
$count = count($slideArray);
<img src="<?php echo base_path() . 'sites/default/files/' .  $slideArray[$i]['filename'] ?>" width="930">
```